# PostgreSQL Adding an index slowed down the query execution drastically even though its not used

Tags: postgresql

I am fairly new to Postgres and I am trying to debug an issue I found recently in which adding an Index has slowed down my query. To begin with, here is the bare bones table that I have. There are more indexes and columns but I am only showing the ones that are relevant to the issue:

```
> \d+ classes
                                                        Table "public.classes"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default          | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 classid      | bigint                      |           | not null | gen_random_js_safe_int() | plain    |              |
 schoolid     | bigint                      |           |          |                          | plain    |              |
 classname    | character varying(255)      |           | not null |                          | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "classes_classname_schoolid_idx" UNIQUE, btree (classname, schoolid) WHERE schoolid IS NOT NULL
Foreign-key constraints:
    "classes_schoolid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (schoolid) REFERENCES schools(schoolid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "classtoschool" CONSTRAINT "classtoschool_classid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (classid) REFERENCES classes(classid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

```
> \d+ classtoschool
                                                     Table "public.classtoschool"
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |           Default           | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 classid           | bigint                      |           |          |                             | plain    |              |
 schoolid          | bigint                      |           | not null |                             | plain    |              |
Foreign-key constraints:
    "classtoschool_classid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (classid) REFERENCES classes(classid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "classtoschool_schoolid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (schoolid) REFERENCES schools(schoolid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

```
> \d+ schools
                                                                  Table "public.schools"
               Column                |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default          | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 schoolid                            | bigint                      |           | not null | gen_random_js_safe_int() | plain    |              |
 schoolStatus                        | character varying(100)      |           | not null |                          | extended |              |
Referenced by:
    TABLE "classes" CONSTRAINT "classes_schoolid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (schoolid) REFERENCES schools(schoolid)
    TABLE "classtoschool" CONSTRAINT "classtoschool_schoolid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (schoolid) REFERENCES school(schoolid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The index in question is:

`"classes_classname_schoolid_idx" UNIQUE, btree (classname, schoolid) WHERE schoolid IS NOT NULL`

Before adding this index, the query execution times are in single digit milliseconds, however, after adding this index, it is triple digits milliseconds sometimes even in seconds under heavy load.
The funniest thing is, that when I run the EXPLAIN, it doesn't even include the index. But for whatever reason, adding the index impacts the query execution time. Another awkward thing is that I have different databases for different regions, and this increase in latency is only observed in this one database. All Postgres versions and settings are identical.

The query that I run is:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE SELECT
  schools.ommitedColumnA,
  classes.classId,
  classes.classname,
  classes.omittedColumnB,
  classes.omittedColumnC,
  classes.omittedColumnD,
  classes.omittedColumnE
FROM
  classes
  LEFT JOIN classtoschool ON (classes.classId = classtoschool.classid)
  LEFT JOIN schools ON (classtoschool.schoolid = schools.schoolid)
WHERE
  (classes.classname = 'maths') AND
  (schools.schoolid = '12345678') AND
  ((schools.banned = false OR schools.banned IS NULL) AND schools.schoolStatus = 'RUNNING') AND
  (schools.schoolStatus != 'BREAK' OR schools.schoolStatus IS NULL);
```

Explain Results:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1834.56..7368.73 rows=2704 width=104) (actual time=3165.232..3191.356 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: classes.classid, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnC, classesomittedColumnD, classes.omittedColumnE
   ->  Index Scan using schools_pkey on public.schools  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=30.811..30.815 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: schools.orgid, schools.schoolid
         Index Cond: (schools.schoolid = '12345678'::bigint)
         Filter: (((NOT schools.banned) OR (schools.banned IS NULL)) AND (((schools.schoolstatus)::text <> 'BREAK'::text) OR (schools.schoolstatus IS NULL)) AND ((schools.schoolstatus)::text = 'RUNNING'::text))
   ->  Gather  (cost=1834.15..7339.05 rows=2704 width=104) (actual time=3134.409..3160.528 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: classes.classid, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnC, classesomittedColumnD, classes.omittedColumnE, classtoschool.schoolid
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=834.15..6068.65 rows=1127 width=104) (actual time=2890.802..3034.482 rows=0 loops=3)
               Output: classes.classid, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnC, classesomittedColumnD, classes.omittedColumnE, classtoschool.schoolid
               Inner Unique: true
               Hash Cond: (classes.classid = classtoschool.classid)
               Worker 0: actual time=2555.322..2986.361 rows=1 loops=1
               Worker 1: actual time=2986.457..2986.459 rows=0 loops=1
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.classes  (cost=0.00..5108.60 rows=47960 width=96) (actual time=3.194..1527.764 rows=38171 loops=3)
                     Output: classes.classid, classes.schoolid, classes.omittedColumnC, classesomittedColumnD, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnE
                     Filter: ((classes.classname)::text = 'maths'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 60282
                     Worker 0: actual time=0.229..1524.734 rows=39144 loops=1
                     Worker 1: actual time=0.255..1524.984 rows=39508 loops=1
               ->  Hash  (cost=747.56..747.56 rows=6927 width=16) (actual time=1502.768..1502.769 rows=2134 loops=3)
                     Output: classtoschool.classid, classtoschool.schoolid
                     Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 165kB
                     Worker 0: actual time=1457.649..1457.649 rows=2134 loops=1
                     Worker 1: actual time=1457.576..1457.576 rows=2134 loops=1
                     ->  Index Only Scan using classtoschool_schoolid_classid_idx on public.classtoschool  (cost=0.42..747.56 rows=6927 width=16) (actual time=12.409..1501.892 rows=2134 loops=3)
                           Output: classtoschool.classid, classtoschool.schoolid
                           Index Cond: (classtoschool.schoolid = '12345678'::bigint)
                           Heap Fetches: 1512
                           Worker 0: actual time=0.134..1456.763 rows=2134 loops=1
                           Worker 1: actual time=0.135..1456.757 rows=2134 loops=1
 Planning Time: 307.276 ms
 Execution Time: 3191.475 ms
```

As you can see, the index `classes_classname_schoolid_idx` is nowhere used.

Below is the EXPLAIN with the index removed:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1834.56..7368.73 rows=2704 width=104) (actual time=41.516..190.198 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: classes.classid, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnC, classes.omittedColumnD, classes.omittedColumnE
   ->  Index Scan using schools_pkey on public.schools  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.034..0.042 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: schools.schoolid
         Index Cond: (schools.schoolid = '12345678'::bigint)
         Filter: (((NOT schools.banned) OR (schools.banned IS NULL)) AND (((schools.schoolstatus)::text <> 'BREAK'::text) OR (schools.schoolstatus IS NULL)) AND ((schools.schoolstatus)::text = 'RUNNING'::text))
   ->  Gather  (cost=1834.15..7339.05 rows=2704 width=104) (actual time=41.477..190.150 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: classes.classid, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnC, classes.omittedColumnD, classes.omittedColumnE, classtoschool.schoolid
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=834.15..6068.65 rows=1127 width=104) (actual time=12.321..17.334 rows=0 loops=3)
               Output: classes.classid, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnC, classes.omittedColumnD, classes.omittedColumnE, classtoschool.schoolid
               Inner Unique: true
               Hash Cond: (classes.classid = classtoschool.classid)
               Worker 0: actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=0 loops=1
               Worker 1: actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.classes  (cost=0.00..5108.60 rows=47960 width=96) (actual time=0.006..13.902 rows=38171 loops=3)
                     Output: classes.classid, classes.schoolid, classes.omittedColumnC, classes.omittedColumnD, classes.classname, classes.omittedColumnB, classes.omittedColumnE
                     Filter: ((classes.classname)::text = 'maths'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 60282
                     Worker 0: actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1
                     Worker 1: actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1
               ->  Hash  (cost=747.56..747.56 rows=6927 width=16) (actual time=1.358..1.359 rows=2134 loops=1)
                     Output: classtoschool.classid, classtoschool.schoolid
                     Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 165kB
                     ->  Index Only Scan using classtoschool_schoolid_classid_idx on public.classtoschool  (cost=0.42..747.56 rows=6927 width=16) (actual time=0.246..1.060 rows=2134 loops=1)
                           Output: classtoschool.classid, classtoschool.schoolid
                           Index Cond: (classtoschool.schoolid = '12345678'::bigint)
                           Heap Fetches: 504
 Planning Time: 5.019 ms
 Execution Time: 190.426 ms
```

Someone suggested I look at the `pg_stat_user_tables` where I found that the value of column `idx_tup_fetch` is vastly different in the database with the index (3 billion) vs without the index (300K).

I have 2 questions:

1. Why & how does the index impact the query execution even though `EXPLAIN` does not show it?
2. Why does the index not impact the query execution in other databases with more rows & data, but only impact this one database?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an index on schoolid, classname ( in that order) would make more sense to me.

Comment: What is the plan after dropping the index?

Comment: Why use left join where retrieve value with specific class and school.

Comment: @jjanes The plan is pretty much identical after dropping the index. The timings are different.

Comment: The difference between pretty much identical, and actually identical, may be large enough to hide the answer.

Comment: @RahulBiswas schoolid is not updated post creation and can also be null at times.

Comment: @jjanes Fair point. I added the EXPLAIN with the index removed.

Comment: This is very weird.  Why do two of the parallel workers return 0 rows instantly in the fast case?  What is the full version of PostgreSQL?  aks `select version()`?

Comment: Your plan uses classtoschool_schoolid_classid_idx, but that is not shown in your list of indexes.